# How to link from other page on the tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have problems with bootstrap tabs in my php page.
I am using two tabs like this on **index.php**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s1"><span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">FIRST TAB</span></a> </li>
  <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s2"><span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">SECOND TAB</span></a> </li>
</ul>
```

And tab content like this

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="s1">Tabe 1 content
    <ul>
       <li>s1_link_A</li>
       <li>s1_link_B</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="s2">Tabe 2 content
    <ul>
       <li>s2_link_A</li>
       <li>s2_link_B</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

My **First Problem** is:

Now I want that when user clink on`<li>s1_link_A</li>` OR `<li>s2_link_A</li>` then First tab must be active and show content. just like when we click on `FIRST TAB`.

Similar when user clink on`<li>s1_link_B</li>` OR `<li>s2_link_B</li>` then Second tab must be active and show content. just like when we click on `SECOND TAB`.

My **Second Problem** is:

I want open both TABS from the other page **index_2.php** using link as

```
<ul>
  <li><a href=""><u>Link to be First Tab</u></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><u>Link to be Second Tab</u></a></li>
</ul>
```

When user click on `Link First Tab` then it must be go to index.php and `FIRST TAB` have to active.
Same thing When user click on `Link Second Tab` then it must be go to index.php and `SECOND TAB` have to active.

Please help for above two problems!

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried adding `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#s1">` inside `li`?

Comment: for the second problem; pass the hash tag in url, use javascript to get hash tag and compare it with tabs and make it active

Comment: i used it <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s1">.But its working only one time. when we conitnue on index.php (realte to first problem) it is not waorking.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle and share with us

Comment: Hey Cerlin! please check http://jsfiddle.net/jr2c34hc/ and help

Answer (score 0):

i've find solution for the first problem
just add

```
<script>
$("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
    $("#"+tab).click();
});
</script>
```

And edit

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
   <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s1" id="tab-1"><span class="hidden-mobile hidden-     tablet">FIRST TAB</span></a> </li>
   <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s2"  id="tab-1"><span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">SECOND TAB</span></a> </li>
</ul>


<!------------AND------------------>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="s1">Tabe 1 content
<ul>
   <li>s1_link_A</li>
   <li><a data-tab-destination="tab-2" >s1_link_B</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="s2">Tabe 2 content
<ul>
   <li><a data-tab-destination="tab-1" >s2_link_A</a></li>
   <li>s2_link_B</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

solution for the SECOND problem

just add in **inddex.php**

```
<script>
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
$('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown', function (e) {
window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
</script>
```

And **edit** in index_2.php

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php#s1"><u>Link to be First Tab</u></a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php#s2"><u>Link to be Second Tab</u></a></li>
</ul>
```

**DONE**